# Microsoft Word 2010 VBA: Find Using Wildcards getting an error that the text contains a pattern match expression which is not valid

Tags: vba, cpu-word

This is the code I have. What I need to do is swap {{300 mm (12 in)}} with {{12 in (300 mm)}}

```
With Selection.Find
    .text = "(\{\{)(?@)( ()(?@)(\)\}\})"
    .Replacement.text = "\1\4\3\2\5"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute replace:=wdReplaceOne
```

The problem is the third section. It won't accept the " (" no matter how I try and write it. If I remove it from the () so it's "({{)(?@) ((?@)()}})" it works fine, but then I can only replace it with {{12 in300 mm)}} because the replacement text gives me errors if I try and add it back in like "\1\3 (\2\4".

Clearly I'm missing some rule but I don't know what. This is my first time trying to work with wildcards and it's particularly difficult with so many special characters I have to account for.

I get the same result if I manually write it into the find window vs adding it to a macro so I'm fairly sure the rest of my code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Text = "(\{\{)([0-9]@ mm) \(([0-9]@ in)\)(\}\})"
.Replacement.Text = "\1\3 (\2)\4"
```

Comment: I may have oversimplified what I'm trying to do. The units aren't standard enough that I can just say "numbers plus a specific acronym". Here are some examples: {{0.45 mm (26 gauge)}}, {{1220 mm (48 inches)}}, {{10 mm (3/8 inch)}}, {{[_____] mm ([_____] inch)}}.  Also, could you explain why the ?@ might be breaking it, or how I can make it recognize \1\3 (\2\4 without giving me an error?

Comment: @Lynn: Use `[0-9]@ [a-z]@` for a number followed by a word. Word regexes are quite poorly documented; see Graham Mayor's [Replace using wildcards](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm) (or even better [here](http://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm)) for something resembling documentation.

Comment: Thanks for that resource! I figured it out. `([!(]@)` and `([!)]@)` work for all units I have to deal with including the blanks ([____]). None of the resources I've seen before have shown the ! as an option.